# Error occurred in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>a demo page</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var formatNum=function(num)
   {
        if(!/^(\+|-)?\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(num)){
            return num;
        }
    var re = new RegExp().compile("(\\d)(\\d{3})(,|\\.|$)");
    num += "";
    while(re.test(num))
        num = num.replace(re, "$1,$2$3")
    return num;
}
alert(formatNum(1000000));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i use these codes to fomat number look like this **1,000,000**  it works well in firefox , but not work in chrome

here is the error shows in chrome **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'test' of undefined** 
how can i resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

The [RegExp().compile()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Methods) method is deprecated.

Why don't you use your regex like this -:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("(\\d)(\\d{3})(,|\\.|$)");
```

Comment: Using a regex literal is recommended. `var regexp = /(\d)(\d{3})(,|\.|$)/;`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>a demo page</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var formatNum=function(num)
   {
        if(!/^(\+|-)?\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(num)){
            return num;
        }
    var re = new RegExp();
    re.compile("(\\d)(\\d{3})(,|\\.|$)");
    num += "";
    while(re.test(num))
        num = num.replace(re, "$1,$2$3")
    return num;
}
alert(formatNum(1000000));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Reason is chrome doesn't return a reference to the compiled RegExp object when calling compile().

So this line  `var re = new RegExp().compile("(\\d)(\\d{3})(,|\\.|$)");` will not work instead a less flexible version needs to be followed.

```
 var re = new RegExp();
 re.compile("(\\d)(\\d{3})(,|\\.|$)");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's deprecated, and not working in firefox too. Maybe your version is an old one.

[Deprecated and obsolete features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Methods)

Use `@Raoul`'s suggestion.